# ClassFileTransformer + Javassist: no such field

Tags: java, javassist, javaagents

Ok, what I am trying to do is doing a java agent that would monitor an application. So, I am trying to inject code in PreparedStatements to measure SQL queries execution times. To do that, I have developped a class implementing ClassFileTransformer. It looks like that:

```
public class JDBCClassTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass currentClass = null;
        CtClass statement = null;
        try {
            currentClass = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
            statement = pool.get("java.sql.PreparedStatement");
            if (currentClass.subtypeOf(statement) && !currentClass.isInterface()) {
                probeStatement(currentClass);
            }
            classfileBuffer = currentClass.toBytecode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (currentClass != null) {
                currentClass.detach();
            }
        }
        return classfileBuffer;

    }

    private void probeStatement(CtClass currentClass) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
        CtField field = CtField.make("private fr.mael.package.SQLProbe $$probe;", currentClass);
        currentClass.addField(field);
        CtMethod setter = CtNewMethod.make("public void set$$probe(fr.mael.package.SQLProbe probe){ this.$$probe = probe;}", currentClass);
        currentClass.addMethod(setter);

        CtMethod executeQuery = currentClass.getMethod("executeQuery", "()Ljava/sql/ResultSet;");

        executeQuery.insertBefore("this.$$probe.start();");
        executeQuery.insertAfter("this.$$probe.stop();");
    }

}
```

So, what I want to do is injecting code in each class (in the "executeQuery()" method) that implements java.sql.PreparedStatement.
To test it, I am just running a basic "select * from a_table" on a MySQL database with the agent attached to the JVM. But I am getting the following exception:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such field: $$probe
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:725)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:685)
```

It happens on the line `executeQuery.insertBefore("this.$$probe.start();");`.
What is weird is that is does not happen each time the "probeStatement" method is executed: the method is first called for the class `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement`, and no exception is thrown. Then, the method is called for the class `com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement`. The exception is thrown. The method is also called for the class `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement` and the exception is thrown too. Both `ServerPreparedStatement` and `JDBC4PreparedStatement`extend `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` so maybe it is somehow related...

I am new to javassist and java agent things, so maybe the answer is obvious, but I can't get why this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is this:
You are adding field `$$probe` in currentClass (your `public class com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement extends com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement`, not directly implements `java.sql.PreparedStatement`) but your are override method `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` (**from javadoc: *CtClass.getMethod()* - The returned method may be declared in a super class.**) and you haven't inject field into `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` and this can cause the compilation error exception (when you instrument `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` no error is thrown because you are inject field into `java.sql.PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` implementor class).
You run into this situation (just an idea):

```
class com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement$$Probed {
  private fr.mael.package.SQLProbe $$probe;

  public void set$$probe(fr.mael.package.SQLProbe probe){ this.$$probe = probe;}
}
class com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement$$Probed {
  public java.sql.ResultSet executeQuery() {
    // this.$$probe in this class doesn't exists! 
    this.$$probe.start();
    ...
    this.$$probe.end();
  }
}
```

Extract from currentClass the first superclass that implements (or `@Override`) `executeQuery()` and inject `$$probe` into or `@Override` `executeQuery()` in your current class

Foe example, overriding `executeQuery()` in currentClass you will have

```
class com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement$$Probed {
  private fr.mael.package.SQLProbe $$probe;

  public void set$$probe(fr.mael.package.SQLProbe probe){ this.$$probe = probe;}

  @Override
  public java.sql.ResultSet executeQuery() {
    this.$$probe.start();
    super.executeQuery();
    this.$$probe.end();
  }
}
```

I hope to be clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: Thank you, you put me on the right track! I actually fixed it by using [getDeclaredMethod](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20javassist.CtClass[]%29). getDeclaredMethod throws a NotFoundException when the method is not declared in the current class. It does not feel right to use a try / catch block, but I could not find a way to test if a method is declared in the class.

Comment: Once found the problem, the solution is under the corner. Hope you can found a good solution soon!